# Is the wording "haven't have had" correct?

Tags: past-tense, have

The other day I started looking for the time of this sentence, I ended up wondering if it is right. I believe I've seen it in some literature, possibly in a movie, but I don't remember the scene or the context it was inserted on, maybe the character was stressed and the phrase would be to show its stress and nervousness.

My first question is: Is the sentence correct? If so, please, can you tell some context in which it is appropriate to use and, finally, which time does it represent?.

The phrase would be "haven't have had". Below is a sample of its use I found on the internet.

> Television is an important product of the Electronic industry YET increasingly difficult to sell ( We haven't have had any 'easy' sales on television yet).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a typo or similar (extraneous ***have*** within ***haven't had***).

Comment: _We wouldn't have had_ is possible. But not the above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an abuse of grammar, which does not belong to Standard English. It should be

> We haven't had any 'easy' sales on television yet.

Some examples from published literature that use the phrase *haven't had any*:

*Since I've been in the minority I **haven't had any** carrots or sticks to move my members.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=1fe-lHYKq0cC&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PT363&dq=%22haven%27t%20had%20any%22&pg=PT363#v=onepage&q=%22haven%27t%20had%20any%22&f=false)
*I **haven't had any** brothers or sisters because you have both been pursuing your careers.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=7NZcBgAAQBAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PA57&dq=%22haven%27t%20had%20any%22&pg=PA57#v=onepage&q=%22haven%27t%20had%20any%22&f=false)
*And you **haven't had any** run-ins with anyone lately?* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=NcnSAwAAQBAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PA36&dq=%22haven%27t%20had%20any%22&pg=PA36#v=onepage&q=%22haven%27t%20had%20any%22&f=false)
*I **haven't had any** sleep or anything to eat since yesterday.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=D1pxLqED1E0C&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PA380&dq=%22haven%27t%20had%20any%22&pg=PA380#v=onepage&q=%22haven%27t%20had%20any%22&f=false)